# How to leave a void method at an arbitrary point in Xtend

Tags: xtend

I want to do a very simple thing in Xtend and don't know how. I have a method with return type `void`. At the beginning of the method a check a condition and want to leave the method, if the condition is not fulfilled, otherwise proceed. Here is an extract from the code:

```
def private void generateODB(BlockDeclaration block) {
   val relevantTypes = block.nestedElements.filter[...]

   // nothing to do: leave!
   if (relevantTypes.empty)
      return

   // ...otherwise do some business logic
}
```

However, I get the exception `"Void methods cannot return a value."` for the `return` statement. I can, of course, make a huge `if` block around the rest of the method body, but isn't it possible just to leave the method at this point? What's the proper syntax in Xtend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We really should give a better error message about what's wrong here.
The problem here is, that

```
someCode
if (somePredicate) 
   return
someOtherCode
```

is interpreted as

```
someCode
if (somePredicate) 
   return someOtherCode
```

So the compiler complains about the result of someOtherCode being returned.

Add a semicolon or a block to tell the compiler what you mean:
I.e.:
    if (somePredicate) {
       return
    }
or:
    if (somePredicate)
       return;

Comment: Ah, now I understand what happens! Thanks a lot for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't wrap the the conditional's then block, i.e. the return statement, in curly braces, like

```
if (relevantTypes.empty) {
      return
}
```

or terminated the return statement by a semi-colon, Xtend considers

```
return

...
```

a single statement. Add a semi-colon or wrap the then block in braces and you will be fine. :-)

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! I upvoted it, but marked Sven Efftinge's reply as answer.

Comment: Thanks ... race conditions are a mess ;-)